# Finding hardware bottlenecks

Tags: benchmarking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out what's the bottleneck slowing down a particular process / the entire system?](https://superuser.com/questions/209438/how-can-i-find-out-whats-the-bottleneck-slowing-down-a-particular-process-the)

When my computer slows down by running a massive program like Visual Studio, how do I determine the specific hardware (eg: RAM, hard drive, CPU, motherboard) that's causing the bottleneck? I imagine I should be using the Resource Monitor or something similar to that but what specific values and metrics should I be paying attention to?